# Change design of C# form without opening a new one?

Tags: c#

I'd like to know if there is a way that I can change the entirety of the layout on my form without having to open a new one, almost as though I am opening an new scene, similar to Unity.

Comment: Reposition controls' `Location` property.

Comment: To change layout of the same controls, you'd need to change location or TOP/LEFT. To use different controls on the same form space, use panels or tabpages.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to display an entirely different page without opening a new form. A not efficient but functional way would be to lay your objects for each page on top of each other and disable/set visible to false for all of the objects you wish not to display. Then alternate which are visible depending on which page you want to display.

P.S I don't recommend doing this because of the inefficiency but if you choose to do so, putting controls for a specific page into a single List will help

Comment: That's what I don't want to end up doing, it would be extremely unorthodox for the program I am writing.

Comment: Well with the information you have provided it would be extremely hard for someone to help you so. We need to know what your trying to do to make accurate suggestions.

Comment: Shannon(above) helped me find my answer.  Thanks for your suggestion anyways!